# How to check for last year?

Tags: c#

I want to calculate the unused vacation days from last year and display them in a grid column . I know I just have to do a simple calculation like:

**VacationDays - UsedVacationDays == leftover vacation days from last year**

but how can I check that I only receive data from last year? I know that there has to be something with `DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1)` at least I think so here's my code so far:

```
public double UnusedVacationDays
{
    get
    {
        return (this.VacationDays - this.UsedVacationDays);
    }
}
```

**Edit**:

```
public double GetUsedVacation(int year)
{
    double hours = 0;
    IEnumerable<HtVacationDay> vacationDays = this.HtVacationDays.Where(x => x.FromDate.Year == year && x.FromDate < DateTime.Today);
    foreach (HtVacationDay vacation in vacationDays)
    {
        TimeSpan span = vacation.ToDate - vacation.FromDate;
        if (span.TotalHours > 8)
        {
            hours += span.TotalHours / 3;
        }
        else
        {
            hours += span.TotalHours;
        }
    }
    return hours / 8;
```

Thanks for the help! ^^

Comment: So, you have two double values (e.g `12.0` and `6.5`) and want to find which part of them related to last year?

Comment: Check the `.Year` property of the dates?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy yes !

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I dont have a .Year property ..

Comment: Well then how do you get "used vacation days" for last year then?

Comment: @TamoDaleko that's impossible, because simple number does not have any information about days, years, age etc. It's simple number and nothing more. You should use something else (e.g. `Vacation` class) instead of simple doubles, or create method which returns vacations days for particular year.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen this is how I get used vacation days

Comment: The problem here is that I don't understand what you're asking. The two numbers does not in any way contain anything that will tell you which year they're from, *unless you create a new type to hold the number*.

Comment: It sounds like you have been given a piece of software by your employer that you don't understand.  You are asking us where to find information in a program we can't see whose data source you don't know and whose data structure we can only guess at from the fragment of code you've shown us.  If you don't know where the data is stored, how can we?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen well sry .. I just want to calcualte the unsed vacation days from last year . so can you tell me if I should wirte a method like the second thing that I posted,  or can I do something in my first code sinpped to get this info .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calculating vacation hours, use date range which falls into your year:

```
public double GetUsedVacation(int year)
 {
    double hours = 0;

    IEnumerable<HtVacationDay> vacationDays = 
        HtVacationDays.Where(x => x.FromDate.Year == year && 
                                  x.FromDate < DateTime.Today);

    DateTime firstDayOfYear = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
    DateTime lastDayOfYear = new DateTime(year, 12, 31);

    foreach (HtVacationDay vacation in vacationDays)
    {
        DateTime from = vacation.FromDate.Date < firstDayOfYear ?
              firstDayOfYear : vacation.FromDate;

        DateTime to = vacation.ToDate.Date > lastDayOfYear ?
              lastDayOfYear : vacation.ToDate;

        var vacationHours = (to - from).TotalHours;            

        if (vacationHours > 8)            
            hours += vacationHours / 3;            
        else            
            hours += vacationHours;            
    }

    return hours / 8;
}
```

Also I believe hours calculation should be much more complex. Because for vacation started on 15:00 and ended next day on 13:00 your code will return 22 total hours. Which divided by 3 gives a little less than `3` hours of vacation. But actually if we have working day from 9:00 AM till 18:00, it should give `5 + 4 = 9` hours of vacation.